# Using Google Calendar API in Bot Framework - Authorize every time?

Tags: c#, oauth, calendar, authorization, botframework

I want my bot (Microsoft Bot Framework in C#) to access my google calendar so that I and others who chat with the bot can view upcoming events. Most of the Google Docs I found show how to authorize a New User's own Google Calendar (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/dotnet and the OAuth 2.0 library)), but I do not want the bot to access the specific User's calendar, just one specific calendar every time.

Will the bot need to authorize repeatedly to view this one calendar? Am I able to embed the credentials in the code so Users are not prompted for Authorization?

Thanks :)

Comment: I think *service account* is created for this purpose

Comment: You're right, that should work perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [Google Service Accounts](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount).

> The Google OAuth 2.0 system supports server-to-server interactions such as those between a web application and a Google service. For this scenario you need a service account, which is an account that belongs to your application instead of to an individual end user. Your application calls Google APIs on behalf of the service account, so users aren't directly involved. This scenario is sometimes called "two-legged OAuth," or "2LO." (The related term "three-legged OAuth" refers to scenarios in which your application calls Google APIs on behalf of end users, and in which user consent is sometimes required.)  Typically, an application uses a service account when the application uses Google APIs to work with its own data rather than a user's data.